# when change display size from settings, the app crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms and a tablet emulator with SO Nougat 7.0 and try to update the display size, but if the app was running before that and I enter again, the app crash showing the next message

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0xc0 (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{ccebd66 #0 id=0xc0}
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

If I open the app again the display size is correct and can see the images bigger or smaller, but I can´t get rid of the crash.

Comment: Can you add the code where this crash happens

Comment: I am not sure, I think is in the activity of android, at least that is what I understand, but apart of that , crashlytics say is in fragmentManager.java line1413.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you doing because i don't think i understand your question quite well

Comment: Android 7.0 and above can chage the size of the icons and the text going to settings, if you do this everything in your cellphone incresa its size, but my app crash and if I opened it again, it shows the new updated size